# How can I access all answers of a Quiz module in phpfox?

Tags: php, phpfox

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;">
{foreach from=$aQuiz.results name=questions item=aQuestion} 
    <div class="clearfix quiz_result_item {if is_int($phpfox.iteration.questions/2)}row1{else}row2{/if}{if $phpfox.iteration.questions == 1} row_first{/if}{if $aQuestion.userAnswer == $aQuestion.correctAnswer} row_is_correct{else} row_is_incorrect{/if}">
        <div class="quiz_result_left">
            {$phpfox.iteration.questions}
        </div>
        <div class="quiz_result_right">
            <div class="txt-dark fs-lg-3 quiz_result_question">{$aQuestion.questionText}</div>

            <table><tr><th style="width:20%px;">Answer Choices</th><th>Correct</th> <th>Your Choice</th> <th>User Statistics</th></tr> </table>
            <div>
                <span class="txt-light">{phrase var='quiz.full_name_s_answer' full_name=$aQuestion.full_name}:</span>
                <span class="txt-dark fw-500">{$aQuestion.userAnswerText}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="txt-light">{phrase var='quiz.correct_answer'}:</span>
                <span class="txt-dark fw-500">{$aQuestion.correctAnswerText}</span>
                <div class="table_left">{phrase var='quiz.answers'}:</div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{/foreach}  
</div>
```

This code shows only the correct answer and userAnswer but I want to access all the answers of a Question I don't how can I access all answers.any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you referenced in your question is Quiz's template. You need to find the source of `$aQuiz`, which is typically in block controllers, or in regular controllers.

In your case, most probably you need to look into `/PF.Base/module/quiz/include/component/controller/view.class.php`.

In `process()` function you need to select questions from table `phpfox_quiz_question` indicating quiz_id in this select. Then you can assign results using `->assign(...)` that is being called in chain of other setters of `$this->template()`.